# rvalue references and constructor arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, rvalue-reference

Lets consider a simple class

```
template< typename T >
class Wrapper {
public:
  // Constructors?
private:
  T wrapped;
};
```

What constructors should it use to be effective?

---

Before C++0x there would be a constructor that takes either:

1. const reference (`T const&`) - if type `T` is "heavy",
2. or value (`T`) - if type `T` is "light".

Determining whether type `T` is "heavy" or "light" is not easy.

One could assume only build-in types (ints/floats/...) are "light". But that is not fully correct since our own `Wrapper<int>` most likely should be considered a "light" type as well.

Libraries like [`boost::call_traits`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) provide some means to overcome this difficulty by allowing type creator to mark the type as "light" (by providing proper `call_traits` specialization). Otherwise it will be treated as "heavy". Seems acceptable.

---

But C++0x makes it worse. Because now you have also rvalue reference (`T&&`) which allows to efficiently take (some) "heavy" objects.

And because of this now you have to chose among:

1. just const reference (`T const&`) - if type `T` is "heavy" and does not support move semantics (because either there is none - like with large PODs - or none was written and you have no influence on that),
2. both const reference (`T const&`) and rvalue reference (`T&&`) - if type `T` is "heavy" and does support move semantics,
3. just value (`T`) - if type `T` is "light" or if it is "heavy" but supports move semantics (even if copy is made it doesn't bother use since otherwise we would have to copy from `T const&` ourselves anyway...).

Still its not easy to tell which types are "heavy" and which are "light" (as previously). But now you are also unable to tell whether type `T` supports move semantics or not (or are you?).

---

This becomes even more annoying once you wrap more than one value since number of possible constructor overloads grows exponentially.

Is there any solution to that problem?

I though about some template constructors for forwarding (perfect forwarding) arguments but I wasn't sure whether that would work as desired. And also it would allow to provide values of different type that would be just forwarded to `T` constructor. This might be considered a feature but does not have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the contrary, C++11 makes it *easier* thanks to universal references:

```
template <typename T> struct Wrapper
{
    T value;

    template <typename U> Wrapper(U && u)
    : value(std::forward<U>(u))
    {  }
};
```

As an extra nice touch, you should add a defaulted second argument that only exists when `T` is constructible from `U`, so as to not make your class itself appear constructible from unmatching types. And make it variadic, too:

```
template <typename ...Args>
Wrapper(Args &&... args,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value, int>::type = 0)
: value(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{  }
```

Make sure to `#include <utility>` for `forward` and `#include <type_traits>` for the traits.

Comment: You can also use a variadic constructor with the same perfect forwarding to construct `value` in place. You just have to write one universal constructor: `template <typename... U> Wrapper(U&&... us) : value(std::forward<U>(us)...) {}`

Comment: Just one question though: the `std::enable_if` is not really necessary here (it does not improve error reporting). What is its use here ?

Comment: So perfect forwarding does do it. Good. Two minor issues thou: (1) How to make Wrapper construct only from T rather than from any U that T could construct from (just out of curiosity). (2) Is there any other way than perfect forwarding? (Again out of curiosity.)

Comment: @AdamBadura: Well, you could provide only a `T const &` and a `T &&` constructor, but that doesn't prevent implicit user-defined conversions: If `T` is implicitly constructible from `U`, then `U()` will bind to `T const &` no matter what you do.

Comment: @AdamBadura: ...or do what Bo Persson says, which is arguably the preferred idiom in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to copy your `T` anyway, it might be better to pass the parameter by value and let the compiler figure out the copying. Whatever you do, there is going to be at least one copy anyway.

```
template< typename T >
class Wrapper {
public:
  Wrapper(T value) : wrapped(std::move(value))
  { }
private:
  T wrapped;
};
```

See [Want speed? Pass by value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) by Dave Abrahams.

Comment: Note that if it's expected that `Wrapper<int&>` is a valid instantiation of `Wrapper` then you'd want to use `std::forward<T>(value)`.

Comment: It seems to me (from the article) that this would hold true if, and only if T was moveable. If it is not this will be suboptimal. And in a template you never know.

Comment: @Adam - No. If the type has only a copy constructor, the copy can be elided. You will need *one* copy to store the value, but the compiler is allowed to optimize away other unnecessary copying.